# Is there a way to automatically adjust database name, username and password

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently in the process of making a website using PHP and mysql for the database. I'm pretty much juggling between a local server with WAMP for debugging and sending to the live server. So I was wondering if there was a way to automatically adjust the database name, the username and the password according to the server the website is on. Currently, I'm just doing it manually but I keep forgetting about it and it becomes annoying especially since I'm uploading to the live server several times a day for my friends to test. 
I've tried using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but for some reason, it doesn't work. Do you guys have any solution or should I just continue doing it manually?

Comment: Rename your local DB, user and password to match remote one. Or I don't understand question.

Comment: [Detect localhost or live environment in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753249/localhost-live-detect-by-http-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to go about it.

- Check for server name with [gethostname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php) and switch credentials based on that.
- Create a file on each server with the credentials, with the same name/path. Do not update that file when uploading to the live server.

If your code allows for environment files such as `.env`, use that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file, say `/doc/root/path/.env` with server settings. Get mysql credential from it and don't update it with the rest code.

`.env` for your local server and `.env` for a production one.

```
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWD=passwd
MYSQL_DB=dbname
```

and

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('./.env');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an environment class which contains the two states, namely production and development..  For each state enter the different database credentials..  In my case I have a constant in the environment class  which states whether or not I am in production.. The constant is a boolean value true or false. Eg

Environment::PRODUCTION

The production constant will be boolean..

If in production,  it uses the production credentials  else uses development,  vice versa. You can store the credentials in a .ini file or php file.  If it is the former, then make sure the file is outside document root